# HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure asp.net core 2.0

Tags: azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-2.0

### Problem

I already developed my web app and published it to azure with asp.net core 1.1 and it was working fine until I upgraded my web application to Core 2.0 final release and now the app working locally but when I deploy it to Azure It gives me this issue .

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I just update .csproj file with this line of code

> #### HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure
>
> #### Common causes of this issue:
>
> The application process failed to start The application process
> started but then stopped The application process started but failed to
> listen on the configured port
>
> #### Troubleshooting steps:
>
> Check the system event log for error messages Enable logging the
> application process' stdout messages Attach a debugger to the
> application process and inspect

Comment: I did the same thing over the weekend.  Works great locally but pushing it up gives me this same error.  Have you been able to figure anything out?

Comment: Nope I am trying to do so

Comment: @Grandizer see this answer this work for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a bit of searching [this](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements-discussions/issues/2#issuecomment-313816550) worked for me.

Essentially clean out the `wwwroot` folder from a console on your Azure Portal.  Make sure you get the top most `wwwroot` folder (I had a sub `wwwroot` folder for some reason.)

`RD wwwroot /S /D`

Should do the trick.  Then just republish your site.  It would appear that the publish process does NOT delete anything that already exists within the deploy folder.  So you have 1.1 .dlls and 2.0 .dlls.

Hope that does the trick for you.

Comment: note: RD wwwroot /S /Q is what worked for me.  If you have installed application insights you will need to reinstall the extension and restart the app

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem publishing a simple spike app using VS2017 15.7.1 
 - File | New Project, ASP.NET Core Web App, MVC, ASP.NET Core 2.0
 - Build and run on local host
 - Publish to Azure WebApp

Browser displayed error: HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure

[image]

Comment: How did you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the issue HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure, mine was fix by installing the .net sdk

https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/visual-studio-sdks

Answer (score 0):

After upgraded to ASP.NET Core 2.0, you need to add following configuration section to all the .csproj files in the solution.

```
<ItemGroup>
   <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

You could create a new ASP.NET Core 2.0 application to check it. The DotNetCliToolReference configuration section is already in the new ASP.NET Core 2.0 application project file but missed in your upgraded application project file.

Answer (score 0):

I was running 2.0.8, had to downgrade to 2.0.5 then it worked. The 2.0.8 didn't include a the Self-contained deployments (SCD) as supposed which 2.0.5 did.

I'm using VSTS to build and release