# .Net core 2.0 HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I have .net core 2.0 project.It worked in server production before.I added some tasks and add some dll with nuget now I publish project to server but it give 
HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure that error.What is problem with this?This worked before in server why it fail?Why it is work in my pc but not work in server?Why .net core every step is a problem and problem factory?Why microsoft just give error name and don't give error detail?What should I do to see detail error?
here is my website which give error: http://evduzen.net

Note:After I add external login to project It does not work in server-production

[image]

thanks

Comment: Try the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45797464/1202807

Comment: I have faced this issue before, and Windows Event Viewer helped me gather more info about the error.

Comment: @GabrielLuci  hi,I updated guestion(I add the end of guestion ) sorry I forget to add all detail.After I add external login to project it failed.How can I publish nuget dll to server

Answer (score 2):

We fixed this by downloading the lastest Windows hosting exe from https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows

Make sure the name ends with ..WindowsHosting.exe

Comment: Installing the latest Windows hosting, solved my issue when I faced it.

Comment: hi @markRedman ,I updated guestion(I add the end of guestion ) sorry I forget to add all detail.After I add external login to project it failed.How can I publish nuget dll to server

Comment: If you reference any new libraries you will need to re publish the whole application.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem.

In addition to installing of [Windows Server Hosting](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archives/2.0.7-download.md#windows) I had to specify conrete path to `processPath` and `arguments` in web.config:

```
<aspNetCore  processPath="C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" arguments="C:\...\MyApp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
```

Also I had to change app pool indetity in IIS from `ApplicationPoolIdentity` to `LocalSystem`.

If it doesn't help then try to set `stdoutLogEnabled=true` in web.config and be sure that folder for logs exists. It can help to figure out the original issue.